# Updating full table instead of matched record problem

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I am writing a PostGIS query in which I have to update the geometry column in table A with the value of the geometry column in Table B.

Table B contains only 300 Rows while Table A contains more than 40000 rows.

The problem is that the query is updating complete table A (40000 rows) instead of only updating rows where the join is valid.

Here is my query

```
UPDATE osm_2023_roads
SET way=tab2.geom
FROM osm_2023_roads tab1 
INNER JOIN
roads2023insideborderchecking tab2
ON tab1.osm_id=tab2.osm_id
WHERE tab1.osm_id=tab2.osm_id;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`UPDATE..FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.183.6) creates an implicit join. You don't need to use the target table as the source, then join to it. If you do, it will result in a self-join:

> Do not repeat the target table as a *`from_item`* unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the *`from_item`*).

Which means you accidentally used `osm_2023_roads` as an additional source for an update of its own self, without norrowing down which rows are supposed to update which, and that enables them to match *everything*.
Use only your actual source in the `FROM` list and define how to match its rows to your target's in the `WHERE`:

```
UPDATE osm_2023_roads AS tab1 
SET way=tab2.geom
FROM roads2023insideborderchecking tab2
WHERE tab1.osm_id=tab2.osm_id;
```

---

You can debug things like that by adding a `returning` clause to see which target rows matched which rows in the source. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/7hAhuM_U)

```
create table osm_2023_roads (osm_id, way) as values
  (1,'linestring(0 0,0 1,1 1,1 2,2 2,2 3)'::geometry),
  (2,'linestring(3 0,3 4)'),
  (3,'linestring(5 0,5 -2)');
create table roads2023insideborderchecking (osm_id, geom) as values
  (2,'linestring(99 99,88 77)'::geometry);
```

```
UPDATE osm_2023_roads target
SET way=tab2.geom
FROM osm_2023_roads tab1 
INNER JOIN
roads2023insideborderchecking tab2
ON tab1.osm_id=tab2.osm_id
WHERE tab1.osm_id=tab2.osm_id
RETURNING target.osm_id as "target.osm_id"
         ,tab1.osm_id as "tab1.osm_id"
         ,tab2.osm_id as "tab2.osm_id"
         ,st_astext(tab1.way) as way
         ,st_astext(geom) as geom;
```

You can see the self-join matching everything freely - that's because there's no `WHERE` condition constraining how your updated `osm_2023_roads` target table is supposed to match rows in `osm_2023_roads` posing as a source in the `FROM` list:

| target.osm_id | tab1.osm_id | tab2.osm_id | way | geom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | LINESTRING(3 0,3 4) | LINESTRING(99 99,88 77) |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | LINESTRING(3 0,3 4) | LINESTRING(99 99,88 77) |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | LINESTRING(3 0,3 4) | LINESTRING(99 99,88 77) |

Avoiding the self-join, you're only matching to your source, the way you specified:

```
UPDATE osm_2023_roads AS tab1 
SET way=tab2.geom
FROM roads2023insideborderchecking tab2
WHERE tab1.osm_id=tab2.osm_id
RETURNING tab1.osm_id
         ,tab2.osm_id
         ,st_astext(tab1.way) as way
         ,st_astext(geom) as geom;
```

| osm_id | osm_id | way | geom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | LINESTRING(99 99,88 77) | LINESTRING(99 99,88 77) |

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick help and detailed explanation. Your help has solved the problem.